# how to make <main> 100% height in material ui drawer demo

Tags: html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI drawer question.
For my project I want to the the backround color of the main tag but the problem is that the main tag is only as tall as the content inside.

https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-djfll?file=/demo.js

I can set the height to '100vh' which makes it the full screen size, but with that if I enter more data it doesnt fill the whole screen

width: '100%'
Few Content
https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2l1A.png
Much Content
https://i.stack.imgur.com/avtXE.png

width: '100vh'
Few Content
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNZYK.png
Much Content
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEs7L.png

Comment: `width: 100vh;` doesnt make much sense. `vh`= viewheight. for width use `vw` (viewwidth). Also, where is your code, what isnt working as intended. What prevents you to use an overflow rule?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your HTML file:

```css
    html,
    body {
      min-height: 100vh;
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
    }
    #root {
      display: flex;
      flex: 1;
    }
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-qmc7v?file=/demo.js)

Then add `flex: 1` to your root on line 25 of demo.js

In short: your body needs to be 100vh, then you can flex whatever you need to.

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work, in the Inspector it says that I can't set classes.root to flex: 1 because the element is not a flex-element. However class root is set to display: flex

Comment: @LeM4 did you add the CSS to the HTML file? I don't see any warnings in my codesandbox link. To be honest I've never even heard of the error message you're describing. It does work, because my codesandbox link works.

Comment: I got it! I just had to remove some div tag inbetween

Answer (score 2):

```
content: {
    flexGrow: 1,
    padding: theme.spacing(3),
    height: window.innerHeight, // <= You Need This Line
    background: "yellow"
  }
```